# mapbox offline custom style -> need png

Tags: styles, png, mapbox

I have created a custom style, with custom tileset, which displayed correctly in Chrome, but not in [Safari or in iOS app](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/aerosimple/ck97bly910ie41ip2e382gdzy.html?fresh=true&title=view&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWVyb3NpbXBsZSIsImEiOiJjazA5bWw4azMwOW42M21tbjB0cGU0NjhiIn0.9NOXjExkUdJFgxK7E7QxRw#11.41/47.4805/-111.3614) (tiles are downloaded for offline). 
I am trying to figure out how to specify that I require png tile set and so far came up with nothing.
Can you please point me in the right direction?

Edit: Perhaps it is not png, vs jpeg after all and something else that is not configured correctly, but the guess so far is that it is due to the fact that jpeg is not transparent and thats why custom layer sent as jpeg does not show layer below. Although I am not sure why it is working in Chrome and not in Safari

Answer (score 1):

Your raster tiles are being rendered as expected in Chrome but not Safari, because Chrome supports WebP images.

You can see detailed discussion of the issue [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5856#issuecomment-237379739). The linked issue also discusses possible workarounds such as turning the image into an Image source on the map. Unfortunately, there's no easy solution to implement on the Mapbox side because of the limitations of the JPG format and browser support for WebP.

Comment: yes I should have updated my question with an answer, but I marked your answer as correct. Thanks for taking the time.